# Sklearn digits dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

digits = datasets.load_digits()

print(digits.data)

classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.4, C=100)
x, y = digits.data[:-1], digits.target[:-1]

x = x.reshape(1,-1)
y = y.reshape(-1,1)
print((x))

classifier.fit(x, y)
###
print('Prediction:', classifier.predict(digits.data[-3]))
###
plt.imshow(digits.images[-1], cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

I have reshaped the x and y as well. Still I'm getting an error saying :

Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 1796]

Y has 1-d array with 1796 elements whereas x has many. How does it show 1 for x?

Answer (score 1):

Actually scrap what I suggested below:

[This link describes the general dataset API](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html#general-dataset-api). The attribute `data` is a 2d array of each image, already flattened:

```
import sklearn.datasets
digits = sklearn.datasets.load_digits()
digits.data.shape
#: (1797, 64)
```

This is all you need to provide, no reshaping required. Similarly, the attribute `data` is a 1d array of each label:

```
digits.data.shape
#: (1797,)
```

No reshaping necessary. Just split into training and testing and run with it.

---

Try printing `x.shape` and `y.shape`. I feel that you're going to find something like: `(1, 1796, ...)` and `(1796, ...)` respectively. When calling `fit` for classifiers in scikit it expects two identically shaped iterables.

The clue, why are the arguments when reshaping different ways around:

```
x = x.reshape(1, -1)
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Maybe try:

```
x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
```

---

Completely unrelated to your question, but you're predicting on `digits.data[-3]` when the only element left out of the training set is `digits.data[-1]`. Not sure if that was intentional.

Regardless, it could be good to check your classifier over more results using the scikit metrics package. [This page has an example of using it over the digits dataset](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-classification-plot-digits-classification-py).

Comment: It give an error : `Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [114944, 1796]`

Comment: @lithum what's the result of printing `x.shape` and `y.shape` like I suggested?

Comment: @linthum Actually made some changes. We're both wrong.

Comment: I reshaped it because it gives a warning .19 verison of sklearn. `DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)`

Answer (score 0):

The reshaping will transform your 8x8 matrix to a 1-dimensional vector, which can be used as a feature. You need to reshape the entire X vector, not only those of the training data, since the one's you will use for prediction need to have the same format.

The following code shows how:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

digits = datasets.load_digits()


classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.4, C=100)
x, y = digits.images, digits.target

#only reshape X since its a 8x8 matrix and needs to be flattened
n_samples = len(digits.images)
x = x.reshape((n_samples, -1))
print("before reshape:" + str(digits.images[0]))
print("After reshape" + str(x[0]))


classifier.fit(x[:-2], y[:-2])
###
print('Prediction:', classifier.predict(x[-2]))
###
plt.imshow(digits.images[-2], cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()

###
print('Prediction:', classifier.predict(x[-1]))
###
plt.imshow(digits.images[-1], cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

It will output:

```
before reshape:[[  0.   0.   5.  13.   9.   1.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.  13.  15.  10.  15.   5.   0.]
 [  0.   3.  15.   2.   0.  11.   8.   0.]
 [  0.   4.  12.   0.   0.   8.   8.   0.]
 [  0.   5.   8.   0.   0.   9.   8.   0.]
 [  0.   4.  11.   0.   1.  12.   7.   0.]
 [  0.   2.  14.   5.  10.  12.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   6.  13.  10.   0.   0.   0.]]
After reshape[  0.   0.   5.  13.   9.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.  13.  15.  10.  15.   5.
   0.   0.   3.  15.   2.   0.  11.   8.   0.   0.   4.  12.   0.   0.   8.
   8.   0.   0.   5.   8.   0.   0.   9.   8.   0.   0.   4.  11.   0.   1.
  12.   7.   0.   0.   2.  14.   5.  10.  12.   0.   0.   0.   0.   6.  13.
  10.   0.   0.   0.]
```

And a correct prediction for the last 2 images, which weren't used for training - you can decide however to make a bigger split between testing and training set.